# CodeContracts unproven in ServiceBase

Tags: .net, windows-services, code-contracts

I have following code in autogenerated part of windows service class (ServiceBase derived):

```
                private void InitializeComponent()
                {
                    components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
problem line 32:    this.ServiceName = "QueueService";
                }
```

and Code Contracts enables, i see few warnings, which i doubt are correct:

```
Warning 5   CodeContracts: requires unproven: !value.Contains("/")  ...\QueueService.Designer.cs    32  4   ...
Warning 6   CodeContracts: requires unproven: !value.Contains("\\") ...\QueueService.Designer.cs    32  4   ...
Warning 7   CodeContracts: requires unproven: value.Length <= MaxNameLength ...\QueueService.Designer.cs    32  4   ...
```

What is the problem with this code, and how fix this warnings?

Comment: Does it compile without that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that currently Code Contracts doesn't "look inside" strings, even if they are compile-time constants, so it doesn't know anything about whether or not the contract will be satisfied.

For example, the following will give a warning:

```
var test = "test";
Contract.Assert(!test.Contains("/")); // Warning here
```

You can use `Contract.Assume` to silence the warnings.

For example:

```
var test = "test";
Contract.Assume(!test.Contains("/"));
Contract.Assert(!test.Contains("/")); // no warning
```